# Using d3.js how to show information on a specific location on a map without using latitude and longitudes data in csv?

Tags: d3.js

I have two csv files say One.csv having data of city, latitude, longitude. Two.csv have city, city-info column. Now I am able to draw the map but could not show city-info information exactly on that city because I don't have latitude and longitude columns in two.csv. Can anyone please give me a tip to resolve it?

Comment: You need to combine the information in the two files, using city as a key to match entries.

Comment: @Lars - That's true but I am not able code it in d3. I am trying to match the city and trying to write city.info but getting undefined error on console.

Comment: If you show us your code we may be able to help you with it.